# error in Analyzer while creating an index

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, mapping, analyzer

I am trying to create an index in elasticsearch with the following settings. I am facing the following error

> error:
>   RemoteTransportException[[ys2order-stg2-01][inet[/64.101.206.15:9300]][indices:admin/mapping/put]];
>   nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [autocomplete] not found for
>   field [DESCRIPTION_AUTO]];  status: 400

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 20
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          " autocomplete": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      "refresh_interval": -1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "number_of_shards": 4,
      "index_analyzer": "default_index",
      "search_analyzer": "default_search"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "itemsnew": {
      "properties": {
        "DESCRIPTION_AUTO": {
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove a space in your analyzer name:

```
    "analyzer": {
      " autocomplete": {       <--- remove initial space here
        "type": "custom",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_filter"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "standard"
      }
    ....
    "DESCRIPTION_AUTO": {
      "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",   <-- because there is no initial space here !!!
      "search_analyzer": "standard",
      "type": "string"
    }
```